# Coding Bat Java Fails Other Tests

Tags: java, string

I'm practicing basic java problems on codingbat, and on a certain problem, my code fails the "other tests". The problem is xyzThere, and the task is this : 
Return true if the given string contains an appearance of "xyz" where the xyz is not directly preceeded by a period (.). So "xxyz" counts but "x.xyz" does not.
Here is my code :

```
public boolean xyzThere(String str) {
  boolean hi = false,hi2 = false;
  for(int i = 0;i<str.length()-2;i++){
    if(i==0)
      hi =  (i==0&&str.substring(0,3).equals("xyz"));
    else hi2 = (str.substring(i,i+3).equals("xyz")&&str.charAt(i-1)!='.');
  }

  return hi||hi2;


}
```

Why is it failing these tests?

Edit: modified my solution so the value of the variables isn't reset, still causing errors

```
    public boolean xyzThere(String str) {
  for(int i = 0;i<str.length()-2;i++){
    if(i==0&&str.substring(0,3).equals("xyz"))
      return true;
    else if(str.substring(i,i+3).equals("xyz")&&str.charAt(i-1)!='.');
      return true;
  }
  return false;


}
```

It's returning true for xyzThere("abc.xyz"), xyzThere("abcxy"), xyzThere(".xyz"), and xyzThere("12.xyz").

Comment: Well, each time through the loop, you're resetting `hi2`.  So if it found the string you want, but it wasn't at the end of the input, then `hi2` would finish up false.  You should just return `true` as soon as you find a match.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw Actually, `i` *must* be 0 in the `if`.

Comment: ah I see, thank you

Comment: @shmosel if its not 0, then it just runs the else, which is also resetting a variable

Comment: But if it is 0, there's no point in checking twice.

Comment: Sure, @shmosel but that's not the reason for the failure.  My apologies for posting an answer in a comment.  I should know better - but I didn't really have time to post a proper answer.

Comment: @DavidWallace I never indicated it was the problem, just commenting.

Comment: @DavidWallace  modified the code but it still seems to be failing some tests

Comment: While you're learning to code, please also pay attention to proper style and readable code ("clean code"). In the long run this is as important as being able to 'just make it work', at least in my professional experience.

Comment: Get rid of the semicolon at the end of the `else if` line.

Comment: @DavidWallace oh! didn't even notice, thanks for the help

Comment: @C-Otto How would I make this code more readable?